# How write a new file in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-io, loadview

First I want to load a view file into a variable, then I need to create a new file by writing the data to new file.ie,Like creating a copy of a view file.

```
$vPath = "home/muhammed/desktop/newfolder";
$ViewData=$this->load->view('test/show',TRUE);
mkdir($vPath);
write_file("$vPath/test.php", $ViewData);
```

But the code given is not working.

Comment: Have you checked the obvious things such as directory permissions, path name correct etc? Have you tried writing directly with [fwrite](http://php.net/fwrite) to get direct output? Need more information.

Comment: file writing is working when I assign string to variable `$ViewData`,ie, `$ViewData='test writing content'`. When I am trying to load a view file, It will not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change:

```
$ViewData=$this->load->view('test/show',TRUE);
```

to

```
$ViewData=$this->load->view('test/show', "", TRUE);
```

as second parameter of `load->view` is data and last param TRUE makes it string to be loaded to the variable
See: [codeIgniter Views](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html)