# how to generate a dynamic css file using php or codeigniter

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I want to develop a project  with dynamic css file ,i mean i want to apply styles dynamically with out using static css file. 
I want to apply styles like colors, borders, width, heights etc..from one form fields and those are stored in database and i want to get values from database and apply changes dynamically in css file(styles), project css applied as dynamically.How can i write code in this scenario

.css file

```
#border
{
  border: 30px;
}
#color
{
  color: red;
}
```

like this...
php form view

```
     <h1 id='color'>hello world</h1>
     <input type='text' id='border' value='hello'/>
```

i want my .css file like this

```
  #border
{
  border: <?= $settings[0]->border ?>;
}
#color
{
  color: <?= $settings[0]->color ?>;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using create a `.php` file.

Add logic to it, make it a CSS file (with `.php` extension).

Add `header` parameters in (start of file) PHP file to tell Server that this is a CSS file.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/css');
?>
```

Now, include the the file as a CSS file.

e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CUSTOM_STYLES.PHP"/>
```

This inclusion of PHP file with CSS body in it will work as a dynamic CSS file.

Comment: i want generate dynamic css file in separate folder not with php extention

Comment: Apply proper path there for separate folder. You can do it any language, but, the contents should be CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can *inline* this part of css into your HTML template:

```
<style>
#border
{
  border: <?= $settings[0]->border ?>;
}
#color
{
  color: <?= $settings[0]->color ?>;
}
</style>
```

Or you could generate a CSS file, when the `$settings` value changes (to take advantage of browser caching)

Comment: thank you but i want generate css file dynamically in separate folder help me how it is..

Comment: So you want to create and save a CSS file, based on a template?

Comment: Two steps: [get your view into a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11772651/load-view-into-a-variable) and [save this variable to a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956300/how-write-a-new-file-in-codeigniter)

Comment: You have two examples in my previous comment: create a `css.php` file in your template folder (with your CSS content and variables), render this template (using my first link) and save it as a `style.css` file using the second link.

Comment: can you provide any previous example link

Comment: Did you give it a try?